# Unset Router::extensions()

Tags: excel, cakephp

I am using [dakota's CakePHP Excel](https://github.com/dakota/CakeExcel) plugin to generate excel pages in my app. I also have a certain place where I'm trying to display xlsx/xls documents in my app. The issue is, this line causes the app to look for and `xlsx` directory in my templates.

```
Router::extensions('xlsx');
```

I can remove that line, and just add it in the controllers that I need it, but this means I'll need to update controllers every time I need to add this functionality, while I know that there is definitely only ONE place where it will not be used.

How can I remove the Router extension in this one instance?

I've tried doing all of these at the top of the action that I need it:

```
Router::extension('', false);
Router::extension(null, false);
Router::extension([], false);
```

None of these work. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want this to be applied, then I'd suggest to not load the plugins routes in the first place, ie set the `routes` option in the `Plugin::load()` call to `false` (or do not specifiy the `routes` option at all, as it defaults to `false`):

```
Plugin::load('CakeExcel', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => false]);
```

Then you can apply the extension in your own routes configuration to only those routes where you actually need it.

Furthermore if you'd really needed to remove global extensions, you can utilize the second argument of `Router::extensions()` to disable merging, respectively to enable overwriting.

```
$extensions = Router::extensions();
$extensions = array_diff($extensions, ['xslx']);
Router::extensions($extensions, false);
```

This will however only work when applied at the right time, that is *after* the `Plugin::routes();` call in your routes configuration, which might be problematic, as other plugin routes can pick up the extensions before you are able to remove them, so you're better of not loading the problematic routes configuration in the first place.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Core\Plugin::load()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#_load)**
- **[API > \Cake\Routing\Router::extensions()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_extensions)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setExtensions`: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions

> This will enable the named extensions for all routes that are being
>   connected in that scope after the setExtensions() call, including
>   those that are being connected in nested scopes

Comment: not entirely sure what the setup looks like in your mind, but I tried doing it using setExtensions, and the result is the same.